# JSON to SQL Server: Convert sub-array of values to column

Tags: sql-server, json, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I have JSON like

```
{  
    "url": {
        "web_categories": [{ "id": 226 } , { "id": 401 }]
  },  
   "account":"Basic"  
}
```

I would like to output in SQL a column that contains the IDs of all `web_categories` a URL was matched to.

```
| webcat |
|--------|
| 226    |
| 401    |
```

Using SQL Server 2016 / Azure SQL DB's support for JSON, how would one achieve that?

### Reproducible example

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo VARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @jsonInfo =N'{  
    "url": {
        "web_categories": [{ "id": 226 }]
  },  
   "account":"Basic"  
}'
```

### Previous iterations

```
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo)  with (webcat varchar(12) '$.url.web_categories.id[0]')
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo)  with (webcat varchar(12) '$.url.web_categories.id')
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo)  with (webcat varchar(12) '$.url.web_categories')
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo,'$.url.web_categories.id[0]')
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo,'$.url.web_categories.id')
select * from openjson(@jsonInfo,'$.url.web_categories')
select JSON_QUERY(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories.id[0]') webcat
select JSON_QUERY(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories.id')    webcat
select JSON_QUERY(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories')       webcat
select JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories.id[0]') webcat
select JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories.id')    webcat
select JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo, '$.url.web_categories')       webcat
```

Comment: Are you going to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: Marked as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default schema, records are returned with a `value` column that contains JSON for each item in the array. This JSON then needs to be processed.

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo VARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @jsonInfo =N'{  
    "url": {
        "web_categories": [{ "id": 226 },{ "id": 411 }]
  },  
   "account":101  
}'  


 SELECT JSON_VALUE(value,'$.id') AS ids FROM OPENJSON(@jsoninfo,'$.url.web_categories')
```

Comment: In this case, explicit schema mightt be better choice because it will directly cast ids to int:

select id 
from openjson(@jsonInfo,'$.url.web_categories') with (id int)